# Script not working when url was changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used to be able to log in with the following code to a URL. It alerts me if the log in details are wrong and logs me in when it is correct.

The URL changed slightly and right now, I am not able to log in. I do not even get the alert message saying the input is wrong. Nothing happens.

Old URL where it was working fine:
http://softwarehuttest.x10.mx/public/account/login/?id=notmyid&password=notmypassword

new URL where nothing happens:
http://softwarehuttest.x10.mx/public/account/login/?id=notmyid&password=notmypassword&rank=22

Rank is always going to be a same number (22 is just an example); thus, I don't want the user to have to input that. I just added an input for rank to test if that is the issue, but the problem persists.

If I directly input the URL with the log in details to a browser, it works.

I don't get what went wrong considering the codes were working fine prior to the URL change. Please advice. Thank you.

```
    <html>

    <script>
    $(document).on("pageinit", "#loginForm", function () {
        $("#form1").on("submit", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://softwarehuttest.x10.mx/public/account/login/",
                data: $("#form1").serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data.loggedIn) {
                        $.mobile.changePage("#home");
                    } else {
                        alert("You entered the wrong username or password. Please try again.");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>

    <div data-role="page" id="loginForm" data-theme="e">
            <!--Start of Log In Page-->
            <header data-role="header">
                 <h1>Log In</h1> 
            </header>

            <!--OLD FORM-->
            <form id="form1" name="form1" method="GET" action="http://softwarehuttest.x10.mx/public/account/login/">
                <label for="id">Username   </label>
                <input type="text" name="id" id="id" />

                <label for="password">Password   </label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />

                <label for="rank">Rank   </label>
                <input type="rank" name="rank" id="rank" />

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/>    
            </form>

            <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <h1></h1>
            </footer>
        </div>
</html>
```

Comment: I would caution you against using GET for usernames and passwords.

Comment: Add an error callback and see what error code you get. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  Since you changed the URL, you might be getting a 404 or something similar.

Comment: Exactly.  People can write code to scrape the username and password out of your URL.

Comment: The url works when I log in directly to a browser. I am not getting 404.

Comment: Regards to security - Did come across that subject while browsing here. Yet to figure out how I can wrap it and make it more secure.

Comment: You should use POST.  It will hide the variables from the URL.  In your ajax, you need to specify the type as POST and then change $_GET to $_POST in your PHP script on the receiving end.

Comment: Tnks will look into that. I don't have access to the server end so will work it out with the guy on that end.

Comment: I just tried logging in using just the html w/o any javascript and it works. The script is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code on JSFiddle and it apparently works. I got the response:"{"loggedIn":false}"

If you want to simply "hide" the Rank input, you can use input type HIDDEN instead of TEXT with the value set to 22.

```
<input type="hidden" name="rank" id="rank" value="22">
```

Comment: That would be a correct response. This is weird.. Can I get a link to your fiddle